# Unable to access template base class' static member without explicit scope

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, static

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7RWYZdkaxUoeW4RS)

A template class with a static member `foo`.

```
template <typename... T>
struct A {
    static constexpr bool foo = true;
};
```

A templaed derived class of A trying to access foo.

```
template <typename... T>
struct B  : A<T...> {
    void yo() {
        std::cout << foo << '\n';
    }
};
```

This fails. Can anyone explain why?? I  can solve it by accessing it directly, like `A<T...>::foo` but what if B has it's own static variable hiding foo??

If a third party/main knows A or B only by a template say `TClass`, how can they access `TClass::foo`without knowing internals?

Comment: As is, `foo` is a non dependent name, you may also use `this->foo` to make it dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `foo` is a non-dependent name, but `A` is a dependent base class which depends on the template parameter `T...`. Standard C++ says that non-dependent names won't be looked up in dependent base classes.

As you said, using `A<T...>::foo` works fine, because it's a dependent name. Identically, `B::foo` works fine too.

You can

```
void yo() {
    std::cout << A<T...>::foo << '\n';
    std::cout << B::foo << '\n';
    std::cout << this->foo << '\n';
}
```

or

```
using A<T...>::foo;
void yo() {
    std::cout << foo << '\n';
}
```

Comment: `std::cout << B::foo << '\n';` Thanks. So externally accessing foo is fine even if B::foo hides A::foo, I will always get the correct foo.